# need example of a strictly positive compact operator on a Hilbert Space

Tags: operator-theory

Give an example (if it exists) of a strictly positive compact operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert Space

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I got the answer it was simple, Consider $l^2(\mathbf R)$  with the orthonormal basis $\{(1,0,0\cdots),(0,1,0,\cdots) \}$ and consider the infinite diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(1, 1/2, 1/3,\cdots)$ which is a compact operator. This is a strictly positive compact operator.